# Why it is showing error while setting background color using Colors.color_name[value] in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to the flutter.
My Question is why I am getting below error in VS Code ?
As I have seen we can change color by Using Color Widget but it is showing error.
Anyone pls tell me why I am getting it ? Or what I did wrong here ?

Below is My Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(){


    runApp(MyApp());

 }


 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context){

  return MaterialApp(
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('My First App', style : TextStyle(
      backgroundColor : Colors.lightBlue[800], //here I am getting Error
      fontSize: 50,
    )),
    ),

  ),
   theme : ThemeData(
   
      primaryColor : Colors.purple,
    ),
   
   );
 }

}
```

I commented the code where I got an error.
Thanks.

Comment: remove the const keyword from title: const Text(

Comment: Please post the error you got. Your compiler already figured out what is wrong and gave you an error message. We should not need to do that again.

Comment: Thankyou very much @ahmetakil. I know its a silly mistake but to be honest I was not really aware about it. Thanks. But It would be really helpful if you could give little explanation on why it was not working with const keyword. As per my knowledge const means we can't change that thing but we can specify the value while creating it . isn't it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `const` keyword for Text Widget because you are giving a variable as a value.

Comment: Could you please explain why it didn't work with const ? or any reference would be really helpful.

Comment: A constant widget expects constant values not state changing values